# Colossatron & Mr. Cuddles

Tags: jetpack-joyride

There is a mission called 'Destroy Mr. Cuddles x times'. Can I do it with Colossatron instead? I tried looking it up but It doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 4):

Colossatron is just a skin for Mr Cuddles, meaning any mission with Mr Cuddles involved can be done with Colossatron, the same concept as using a golden Mr Cuddles.

Mr Cuddles with Colossatron skin:

[image]

For some backstory, the Colossatron skin is a reference to a Halfbrick game of the same name, [Colossatron](http://halfbrick.com/our-games/colossatron/).